# display buffer output from expect

Tags: bash, shell, expect

Im' trying to execute a python file that prompt for password within my bash script and I need to display execution output (buffer?):

```
GrabIt=$(expect -c '
spawn python grabber.py ../MyDir
expect "* password? "
send "'${PASSWORD}'/r" 
send $expect_out(buffer)
')
echo $GrabIt
```

Thanks

Comment: So is any problem you get in displaying output?

Comment: Like  `puts "The output is '$expect_out(buffer)'."`?

Comment: It dosen't work i get this error msg 
./test.sh: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: command substitution: line 14: `  puts "this is a test '$expect_out(buffer)'"'

Comment: quoting issues: remove the single quotes from the `puts` string

Comment: Now I'm getting:
        > ./test.sh                                                                                                
        spawn python grabber.py ../MyDir
seems that python script is not executed , i have no output :/

Comment: In order to enable us to analyze your issue, you have to provide `grabber.py` or reduce the problem to a case without further dependencies.